# After upload a file in Android Firebase Storage how get the file download Url? getDownloadUrl() not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

In my new android firebase project, I used `com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1` library.

I get the following Error:

[image]

I opened another project that had library `firebase-storage:15.0.2` and `taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();` which worked on that project. but after using latest dependency library it's not working.

Now, how can I get the file URL?

**Any way to get the file download link?**

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I had Found 2 solution for my issue.

[Firebase Google Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url) :

```
//add file on Firebase and got Download Link
filePath.putFile(imageUri).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()){
            throw task.getException();
        }
        return filePath.getDownloadUrl();
    }
}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()){
            Uri downUri = task.getResult();
            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Url: "+ downUri.toString());
        }
    }
});
```

**Another solution!**

It's **more easy and small** than google Firebase documentation and I'll use it:

```
filePath.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: uri= "+ uri.toString());
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

That method has been deprecated on version 16.0.1 (check [Firebase release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)) so you have to use

[StorageReference.getDownloadUrl()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#getDownloadUrl())

If you want to get them after uploading the file, then you must check their documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url). It is already updated.

Comment: Thanks for your info, I didn't found this. I read the documentation and this help me.

Answer (score 2):

taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl() is deprecated so i recommend that in your addOnSuccessListener() method, you use your storageReference and call the getDownloadUrl() method in order to get the url of the file and you can do whatever you want with it. Hope it helps.

```
         mUploadTask = storageRef.putFile(file).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                // get the image Url of the file uploaded
                storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        // getting image uri and converting into string
                        Uri downloadUrl = uri;
                       fileUrl = downloadUrl.toString();


                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

Comment: Hey man, just really want to thank you as I was completely stuck for days and just couldn't find the solution. Tried asking question here but nothing worked. And bang I landed on your answer and now it's working.

Comment: I am glad I could help. Please upvote if the answer was helpful. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

that's how I'm getting download link in kotlin android.

```
 ref.putFile(filePath!!)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
            val result = it.metadata!!.reference!!.downloadUrl;
            result.addOnSuccessListener {

               val imageLink = it.toString()


            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case is better to continue using `addOnSuccessListener` as you're using, but instead of using `getDownloadUrl` directly, you need to **add a listener** to that too.

Now the method is inside `taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference()` like this

```java
filePath.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                 taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        // User uri here
                    }
                });
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase upadated their method so kindly update yourself use this method kindly:

this is the basic line at which you feeling annoying, very simple justget the download path in this way

```
 StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images/"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString());
  UploadTask  uploadTask = ref.putFile(filePath);
  Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot,
         Task<Uri>>() {
   @Override
   public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
     if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
       throw task.getException();
     }

                                                              // Continue with the task to get the download URL
     return ref.getDownloadUrl();
   }
 }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
      if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();


    ///here is your image url enjoy this 

          Toast.makeText(CloudStorageActivity.this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }


      } else {


        // Handle failures
        // ...
      }
    }
  });
```