# How can i upload and retrieve an image to firebase storage in android in 2018 (taskSnapshot/getDownloadUrl deprecated) (Closed)

Tags: android, image, firebase, get, upload

**Update: my problem is solved now.**

How can i upload and retrieve an image to firebase storage in android in 2018 (`taskSnapshot/getDownloadUrl` deprecated).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After upload a file in Android Firebase Storage how get the file download Url? getDownloadUrl() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50570893/after-upload-a-file-in-android-firebase-storage-how-get-the-file-download-url-g)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution. And its working pretty fine.

```
filePath.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: uri= "+ uri.toString());
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  imageFilesPath = storageReference.child("Your_collection Name" + "/"+ "Image_name"+ ".jpg");

  imageFilePath.putFile(image_Uri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful() && task != null) {
                imageUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();
          }
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @globlin said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50571790/3681565):

> That method has been deprecated on version 16.0.1 (check [Firebase
>   release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)) so you have to use
>
> [StorageReference.getDownloadUr()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#getDownloadUrl())
>
> If you want to get them after uploading the file, then you must check
>   their documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url). It is already updated.

So, you can follow [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url) guide to know how to do it in 2018.