# Cant Retrieve Firabase Storage image URL

Tags: android

In my app user can upload their image in Firebase storage and database via my app, but i cant retrieve URL of uploaded image to set their profile Image

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

private StorageReference UserProfileImageRef;
String currentUserID;

databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserID);
UserProfileImageRef=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile Images");

databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
    String q=UserProfileImageRef.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "url"+q, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               Glide.with(SetupActivity.this)
                        .load(q)
                        .into(ProfileImage);

            }
        }



        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Io5qr.png)`enter code here`

Comment: i tried this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("profileimage");
```

You forgot to add the child "profileimage"

UPDATE:
Your download url is not same as in the Firebase Storage. I assumed you take the wrong download url.

Refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50572357/9346054

```
filePath.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: uri= "+ uri.toString());
                //You store the download in database.
                //set value databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("profileimage").setValue(uri.toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    //Success store the link in the database.
                    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                }
            }
        });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

UPDATE BASE ON UR ANSWER: 
try this one

```
  Uri resulturi = result.getUri();
        final StorageReference filepath = UserProfileImageRef.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");
        filepath.putFile(resulturi).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    //Okay part ni dia ambik link kat firebase storage akan pergi ke photoUri kat student tuu
                    filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            //Update in database
                            databaseReference.child("profileimage").setValue(String.valueOf(uri));
                            Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });


                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: @VoraRavi I think you have the problem when you want store the download url in the firebase database. I already updated the answer

Comment: no bro, i don't have to problem uploading and string image,only problem is in to retrieve URL of uploaded Image like...(https://.....//.jpg)
if this URL will retrieve than it will fixed

Comment: @VoraRavi the problem is the string url that you stored in the database is not the image url from your firebase storage.

Comment: can you please paste that line for url

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri resulturi=result.getUri();
            StorageReference filepath=UserProfileImageRef .child(currentUserID +".jpg");
            filepath.putFile(resulturi).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task)
                {
                    if (task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        Intent selfIntent=new Intent(SetupActivity.this,SetupActivity.class);
                        startActivity(selfIntent);


                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        final String downloadurl =task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                        databaseReference.child("profileimage").setValue(downloadurl)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                                    {
                                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                                        {
                                            Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            String message=task.getException().getMessage();
                                            Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "error"+message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    }

                                });
                    }

                }
            });
        }
```