# Upload a file to Firebase Storage and get a downloadUrl. How can I return the result in a Kotlin function?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I have a function that uploads a local file to Firestore Storage using `uploadTask`. I followed the instructions given in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files?authuser=0). Here is my code:

```
fun uploadAudioFile(file: File){
    val audioFilePathUri = Uri.fromFile(file)
    val ref = currentUserRef.child("audioFiles/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + "m4a")
    val uploadTask = ref.putFile(audioFilePathUri)

    val urlTask =
        uploadTask.continueWithTask(Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>> { task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                task.exception?.let {
                    throw it
                }
            }
            return@Continuation ref.downloadUrl
        }).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val downloadUri = task.result
                Log.d("STORAGE_UTIL", "downloadUri: " + downloadUri)
            } else {
                // Handle failures
            }
        }
}
```

The function works fine and renders the correct **downloadUri**.

Now my question: I want to rewrite this function so that it returns that *downloadUri*. Something like this:

```
 fun uploadAudioFile(file: File): Uri? {
    val audioFilePathUri = Uri.fromFile(file)
    val ref = currentUserRef.child("audioFiles/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + "m4a")
    val uploadTask = ref.putFile(audioFilePathUri)

    val urlTask =
        uploadTask.continueWithTask(Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>> { task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                task.exception?.let {
                    throw it
                }
            }
            return@Continuation ref.downloadUrl
        }).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val downloadUri = task.result
                Log.d("STORAGE_UTIL", "downloadUri: " + downloadUri)
            } else {
                // Handle failures
            }
        }
    return downloadUri 
}
```

This gives me a **unresolved reference** on the return statement's *downloadUri*.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After upload a file in Android Firebase Storage how get the file download Url? getDownloadUrl() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50570893/after-upload-a-file-in-android-firebase-storage-how-get-the-file-download-url-g)

Comment: @AjahnCharles Your 'possible duplicate' concerns the statement getDownloadUrl() not working while I have no problem getting the downloadUri. My question is about how to return the value of a retrieved downloadUri in a Kotlin function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way you can return your `downloadUri` as a result of a method and this is because Firebase APIs are `asynchronous`. This means that `onComplete()` function returns immediately after it's invoked, and the callback from the `Task` it returns, will be called some time later. So unfortunately there are no guarantees about how long it will take, it may take from a few hundred milliseconds to a few seconds before that data is available. Because that method returns immediately, the value of your `downloadUri` variable you're trying to return, will not have been populated from the callback yet.

Basically, you're trying to return a value synchronously from an API that's asynchronous. That's not a good idea. You should handle the APIs asynchronously as intended.

A quick solve for this problem would be to use the value of your `downloadUri` variable **only** inside the `onComplete()` method. Basically, all the logic that exist inside your `uploadAudioFile()` method should be moved inside the callback. If you want to use that value outside the callback, I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51594772/how-to-return-a-list-from-firestore-database-as-a-result-of-a-function-in-kotlin/51595202)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback.

Comment: Great explanation and a very helpful answer and clean solution in your (highly recommended!) post. I learned something today!