# How to save image url in firebase real-time database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, image-uploading

I want to save image url in real-time database but none of the solutions that I tried is solve the problem, the code that I wrote it saving the image in firebase storage but I want to save the image url in real-time database, so can anyone help?

this code just save the image in firebase storage

```
private Button btn_upload,btn_choose;
private ImageView imageView;
private Uri filepath;
private FirebaseStorage storage;
private StorageReference storageReference;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn_choose= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_choose);
    btn_upload= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_upload);
    imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);

    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    storageReference = storage.getReference();

    btn_upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            uploadImage();

        }
    });

    btn_choose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            chooseImage();

        }
    });



}

// choose image function code

private void uploadImage() {

    if(filepath!=null)     {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StorageReference reference = storageReference.child("images/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());

        reference.putFile(filepath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();
            }
        })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                        double progres = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded"+(int)progres+"%");
                    }
                }) ;


    }   }
```

I want to store image in real-time database

Comment: Show us what have you tried for adding the url in the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After upload a file in Android Firebase Storage how get the file download Url? getDownloadUrl() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50570893/after-upload-a-file-in-android-firebase-storage-how-get-the-file-download-url-g)

Comment: It looks like you haven't made any attempt to write anything at all to Realtime Database.  I suggest starting with the documentation to learn how to read and write the database. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Answer (score 1):

You can request download URL for the file after uploading finishes.
Then Add the URL to Real-time Database

```
  reference.putFile(filepath).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();
                reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                      //You will get donwload URL in uri
                      Log.d(TAG, "Download URL = "+ uri.toString());
                      //Adding that URL to Realtime database
                      mDatabase.child("imageUrl").setValue(uri.toString());
                    }
                });
            }
        })
```

Comment: mDatabase in "mDatabase.child("image").setValue(uri.toString());
                    }” refers to what?

Comment: That line to add data to realtime database. See documentation of  [realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write).

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && data != null && data.getData() != null )
    {
        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

private void uploadImage() {
        name = txtname.getText().toString();

```
    if(filePath != null)
    {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images/"+ name);
        ref.putFile(filePath)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot
                                .getTotalByteCount());
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded "+(int)progress+"%");
                    }
                });
    }

            Toast.makeText(this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```