# Oncomplete task cann't access the method getDownloadUrl() after getResult()

Tags: android, firebase, file-upload, firebase-storage

i was watching a tutorial on how to upload images .. there At certain moment the instructor worte the code to get the download URL after uploading by using getResult method from UploadTask.TaskSnapshot

```
  setup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String username = setupName.getText().toString();
                    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(username)&& mainImageUri!=null){
                            String user_id = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            StorageReference image_path = storageReference.child("Profile_images").child(user_id+".jpg");
                            image_path.putFile(mainImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl();
                                    }else{
                                        String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                                        Toast.makeText(setupPage.this, "Error occured!"+error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                                    pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                }
                            });
                    }
                }
            });
```

can i use getuploadsessionUri instead of getDownloadUri()?

Comment: Getting the download URL for a file now requires an extra asynchronous call, which means you need to attach an extra `addOnCompleteListener` listener. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50572357. I'd also recommend finding a newer tutorial or working from the product documentation, as this API change was made in May 2018.

Comment: image_path.putFile(mainImageUri).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
             @Override
             public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                 Uri sessionUri = taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri();
             }
         });