# How to get download url for firebase storage and update firestore document?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have been struggling to get download url for an image uploaded to firebase storage from my app.
I want to send this url to firestore databse (not realtime database).
I am setting itemImageUri to `uri.toString()` but in `onCreate()` method itemImageUrl is null and shows null in firestore. I cannot use `CollectionRefernece addItemRef` in `onSuccess` method as it gives error for all string variables: Variable is accessed from within inner class needs to be declared final.

```
public class AddItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public class AddItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    public static final String TAG = "Error!";
    public static final String UPLOAD_TAG = "Image uploaded";
    private Uri imageUri = null;
    private TextInputEditText textFieldTitle;
    private TextInputEditText textFieldDesc;
    private AutoCompleteTextView dropdownItemType;
    private TextInputEditText textFieldAddress;
    private TextInputEditText textFieldAvailability;
    private MaterialButton buttonSubmitItem;
    private MaterialButton buttonAddImage;
    private ImageView imageViewItem;
    private String itemImageUrl;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Uri itemImageUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_item);

        imageViewItem = findViewById(R.id.imageView_camera);
        textFieldTitle = findViewById(R.id.textField_title);
        textFieldDesc = findViewById(R.id.textField_description);
        dropdownItemType = findViewById(R.id.dropdown_itemType);
        //Select type dropdown
        String[] itemTypes = new String[] {
                "Food",
                "Clothing",
                "Footwear"
        };
        ArrayAdapter<String> itemsDropdownAdpater = new ArrayAdapter<>(AddItemActivity.this, R.layout.dropdown_item_type, itemTypes);
        dropdownItemType.setAdapter(itemsDropdownAdpater);

        textFieldAddress = findViewById(R.id.textField_address);
        textFieldAvailability = findViewById(R.id.textField_availability);
        buttonAddImage = findViewById(R.id.button_addImage);
        buttonSubmitItem = findViewById(R.id.button_submitItem);

        buttonAddImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(AddItemActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Toast.makeText(AddItemActivity.this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AddItemActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                    } else {
                        choseImage();
                    }
                } else {
                    choseImage();
                }
            }
        });

        buttonSubmitItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                submitItem();
            }
        });
    }

    private void choseImage() {
        CropImage.activity()
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                .start(AddItemActivity.this);
    }

    private void submitItem() {
        String title = textFieldTitle.getText().toString();
        String desc = textFieldDesc.getText().toString();
        String type = dropdownItemType.getText().toString();
        String address = textFieldAddress.getText().toString();
        String availability = textFieldAvailability.getText().toString();
        
        if (title.trim().isEmpty() ||
                desc.trim().isEmpty() ||
                type.trim().isEmpty() ||
                availability.trim().isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Fields cant be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
       
        handleUpload(bitmap);
        CollectionReference addItemRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("ItemList");
        addItemRef.add(new ItemListModel(title, desc, type, address, availability, itemImageUrl));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                imageUri = result.getUri();
                imageViewItem.setImageURI(imageUri);
                imageViewItem.invalidate();
                BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageViewItem.getDrawable();
                bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleUpload(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        final StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("itemImages")
                .child(System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpeg");

        reference.putBytes(baos.toByteArray())
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        getItemImageUrl(reference);
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ", e.getCause());
                    }
                });
    }

    private void getItemImageUrl(StorageReference reference) {
        reference.getDownloadUrl()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        itemImageUrl = uri.toString();
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After upload a file in Android Firebase Storage how get the file download Url? getDownloadUrl() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50570893/after-upload-a-file-in-android-firebase-storage-how-get-the-file-download-url-g)

Comment: @Walid No, this doesnt explain how I would send downloadUrl to firestore database, in my code above I am getting the uri using getDownloadUrl but unable to set ```String itemImageUrl``` to this value.

Comment: So as I understood, you need to upload a file to storage, then get the download link and then upload your object to the database, right ?

Comment: Yes! How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determining the download URL requires a call to the servers, which means it happens asynchronously. For this reason, any code that needs the download URL needs to be inside the `onSuccess` of `getDownloadURL()` or be called from there.

So:

```
private void getItemImageUrl(StorageReference reference) {
    reference.getDownloadUrl()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    itemImageUrl = uri.toString();

                    ... here you can write itemImageUrl to the database
                }
            });

}
```

Also see:

- [How to get the download url from Firebase Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299915/how-to-get-the-download-url-from-firebase-storage/53300660#53300660)

Comment: If I cant use addItemRef.add() in this async task, how would I set itemImageUrl to database?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. You can either create a new document, or add to the existing document inside the `onSuccess`. What problem/error do you get when you try that?

Comment: Thanks!
I called a method from reference.getDownloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener() that creates a firestore document .
```private void getItemImageUrl(final StorageReference reference) {
        reference.getDownloadUrl()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        String downloadUrl = uri.toString();
                        addItem(downloadUrl);
                    }
                });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In NodeJS, to get a link for a document stored in Firebase Storage.

```
const options = {
        version: 'v2', // defaults to 'v2' if missing.
        action: 'read',
        expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60, // one hour
    };

let url = storage
    .bucket(bucketname)
    .file(filename)
    .getSignedUrl(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

First upload the file to the Storage, then call your upload method to the database on the `addOnCompleteListener` :

```
final StorageReference fileReference = storageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                + "." + getFileExtension(uriList.get(i)));
        uploadTask = fileReference.putFile(uriList.get(i));

        uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
            @Override
            public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                if (!task.isSuccessful() && task.getException() != null) {
                    throw task.getException();
                }

                return fileReference.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                    if(downloadUri != null) {
                        itemImageUrl = downloadUri.toString()
                        
                        // create your object
                        // upload your object to the database here
                    }

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have mentioned creating a Collectionreference int this async task gives error: Variable is accessed from within inner class needs to be declared final.

Comment: you can make it a global variable, or create a method for your upload task and call it there.

Comment: Thanks alot! been struggling for 2 days with such an obvious solution. I called a method from ```reference.getDownloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener()``` that creates a firestore document